# Get $response from codeigniter library in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I am using a stripe class in a library for codeigniter. One function ends in:

```
$response = curl_exec( $req );
curl_close( $req );
return $response;
```

I am wanting to know how to get the $response to echo out in the controller that is requesting the data.

In my controller I have the following:

```
$this->load->library('stripe');

$this->stripe->charge_card($amount, $card, $desc);

echo $response;
```

Right now, the controller throws an error saying the `$response` is undefined. I've also tried: `echo $this->stripe->response();` but that gave me the same result.

So if the library does `return $reponse` how can I echo it out in the controller that originally made the request? ex(`echo $response;`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the return value of the function in a variable:

```
$response = $this->stripe->charge_card($amount, $card, $desc);
```

Then do

```
echo $response;
```

So, your new code should look like this:

```
$this->load->library('stripe');
$response = $this->stripe->charge_card($amount, $card, $desc);
echo $response;
```

Comment: So I need to replace `$this->stripe->charge_card($amount, $card, $desc);` with `$response = $this->stripe->charge_card($amount, $card, $desc);` to avoid charging customers twice on every transaction? You may want to clear that up in your answer. For future reference! :) But thank you.

Comment: @user3367639 Yes. You would *replace* that line with the above.